# API Change vs Environment variable to handle debug

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging

I have a client-server application that always connects to localhost in the final product. The client code is in C# and it uses, let's say, a `client.dll` as an abstraction layer for the communication. The `client.dll` always connects to `localhost` assuming the server will run on the same machine and this is fine for the final product, but most of the client developers are working on Windows machines while the server is Linux only and to debug the application is quite tedious at the moment.

My questions is: should I change the API of the `client.dll` to be able to pass the IP of the server or should I use an environment variable with the IP and if it's not set to connect to `localhost`?

Each approach has some advantages:

- the API change is self documented, but more error prone as one can forget to set the IP to `localhost` in the final product and also each developer has to change the IP every time after they checkout the code
- the environment variable is somehow shady and one might forget it is set on the system.

Comment: Do not change the API. Introduce a new method / interface for the new one, mark the old method as deprecated (but do not remove it for a very long time, ideally you could check how often it is used).

Comment: Maybe the experts for such a question are on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, because your question is more architecture / design related

Comment: @ThomasWeller when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: true. Felics, if you decide to post on the sister site, then delete the question here.